# spark sql: error: value === is not a member of String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am new to spark and I am trying to run a sql query using spark

```
df.filter("gene" === "abcd" && "biomarkerName".contains("72fqss") && "tagType" === "pname").select("biomarkerId").distinct().show()
```

Its throws error
value === is not a member of String

I tried using == in place of === and it throws the boolean error

```
error: overloaded method value filter with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (func: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => Boolean)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (conditionExpr: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 cannot be applied to (Boolean)
```

and also I tried to
val spark: SparkSession = ...
import spark.implicits._

but I am not sure what are those ... for and when I try to import spark.implicits._ nothing happened
how to approach this problem

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are not telling spark that the left side of the condition is a column.

You could do something like this without implicits :

```
df.filter(col("gene") === "abcd" && col("biomarkerName").contains("72fqss") && col("tagType") === "pname").select("biomarkerId").distinct().show()
```

Or with implicits :

```
import spark.implicits._
df.filter($"gene" === "abcd" && $"biomarkerName".contains("72fqss") && $"tagType" === "pname").select("biomarkerId").distinct().show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Antony Granger , the above syntax corrected the error but I got other error now as the col("gene") is an array(strings)

Comment: @olive do you have the full error please ?

Comment: thanks for the solution, It worked and you are of big help Thank you so much @Anthony

Comment: Thank you @olive ! :) Feel free to mark the answer as resolved then !